# c# wpf DoubleAnimation/Storyboard PropertyPath

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, doubleanimation

Im trying to animate a curve slowly but i don't know what PropertyPath i should use if i want it to animate from its start point to X2, Y2 point.

```
private void DrawLine(Canvas canvas, double X1, double Y1, double X2, double  Y2, Brush color)
{
    QuadraticBezierSegment qbs = new QuadraticBezierSegment(new Point(X2,   Y1), new Point(X2, Y2), true);

    PathSegmentCollection pscollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
    pscollection.Add(qbs);

    PathFigure pf = new PathFigure();
    pf.Segments = pscollection;
    pf.StartPoint = new Point(X1, Y1);

    PathFigureCollection pfcollection = new PathFigureCollection();
    pfcollection.Add(pf);

    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    pathGeometry.Figures = pfcollection;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.Data = pathGeometry;
    path.Stroke = color;
    path.StrokeThickness = 1;
    canvas.Children.Add(path);

    Storyboard story = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation dAnim1 = new DoubleAnimation(Y1, Y2, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 750)));
    DoubleAnimation dAnim2 = new DoubleAnimation(X1, X2, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 750)));

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dAnim1, new PropertyPath("???"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dAnim2, new PropertyPath("???"));
    story.Children.Add(dAnim1);
    story.Children.Add(dAnim2);

    path.BeginStoryboard(story);

}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you when you don't tell us which properties of which object you want to animate?

Comment: Edited, i forgot that.

Comment: There is no animation in WPF which could do that. You may perhaps use a DispatcherTimer to periodically add data to the PathGeometry.

Comment: Before i tried to make this curve i only had a line drawn and animated, does curves make this process much harder? If it does i might go back to drawing a line only.